# Filter data between two dates in Django rest api

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am creating a react app that uses Django rest APIs. I want to filter data between two date range such that the user can select start date and end date and from the frontend and send a post request to my Django backend and the filtering to be done from the backend. Currently I'm stuck the filtering isn't working. I'm filtering by timestamp(added_on).

My model

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    choices = ((1, "Nairobi"), (2, "Nyanza"),
               (3, "Central"), (4, "Coast"),
               (5, "Eastern"), (6, "North Eastern"),
               (7, "Western"), (8, "Rift Valley"))
    choices1 = ((1, "Pishori"), (2, "Komboka"))

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
    farmer_id = models.ForeignKey(Farmer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kgs = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    packaging = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    transport = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.TextField()
    rice_type = models.CharField(choices=choices1, max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

my serializer

```
class OrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response["farmer"] = FarmerSerializer(instance.farmer_id).data
        response["customer"] = CustomerSerializer(instance.customer_id).data
        return response
```

my view

```
class OrderDateViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrdersSerializer
    queryset = Orders.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = OrdersSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            startDate = serializer.validated_data['startDate']
            endDate = serializer.validated_data['endDate']
            orders = Orders.objects.filter(added_on__gte=startDate, added_on__lte=endDate)
            serializer = OrdersSerializer(orders, many=True)
            dict_response = {"error": False, "message": "Orders Between Dates", "data": serializer.data}
        except:
            dict_response = {"error": True, "message": "An error occured"}

        return Response(dict_response)
```

After sending the request I'm only recieving the error message but I want to recieve the filtered data

Comment: Remove the `try`/`except` and look at the error that is printed in the console... By "swallowing" the exception, you make it hard to debug your program...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to do it but I still don't know why it returns an empty array instead of returning data. I made all the changes in my view.py

```
class OrderDateViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrdersSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        startDate = self.kwargs.get('startDate')
        endDate = self.kwargs.get('enDate')
        return Orders.objects.filter(added_on__range=[startDate, endDate])
```